# Unable to understand the integration for rectifiers

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, semiconductor-physics

I was reading about Rectifiers in books. While finding DC voltage, a time average value of Load Voltage is calculated by integration. The  integration is with time t as a variable, with limits 0 and pi for half wave rectifier.

V(DC) = [image]

= [image]

When I performed the integral, the result is...

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your mistake is that you integrate from 0 to π, instead of 0 to T/2, with T=2π/ω.

Comment: Thank you, this is an error in the textbook probably . It shows the upper limit as pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $V_{DC} = \frac{v_{s}}{T} \int_{0}^{\frac{T}{2}} dt  \sin(\omega t)$ for a half-wave rectifier. Note that the indefinite integral itself evaluates to $-\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}$, which is exactly what you have. Recall that $\omega = \frac{2 \pi}{T}$, so that the average value becomes $V_{DC}= -\frac{v_{s}}{T \omega} \left[ \cos{\frac{2\pi}{T} \frac{T}{2}} - \cos{0}  \right]$. The factor outside is $-\frac{v_{s}}{2\pi}$ while the term in the brackets is just a $-2$, which gives your quoted result.

Comment: Thank You so much! This is an error in the textbook I guess. Thank you.